# What is the relation between spring-security-oauth2-client and spring-security-oauth?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

There is a spring project `spring-security-oauth`
http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

[dev guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)

[Source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/spring-security-oauth2)

And then under `spring-security`,
there is also [oauth](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-security-oauth2-core)

[Source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/oauth2/)

In springboot [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2), it uses `spring-security-oauth2-client`, which is from `spring-security`

And in [springboot OAuth2 tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) , it uses yet another `org.springframework.security.oauth.boot`

What are the differences? And when to use which?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's currently a transition period where spring-security-oauth2 has been put in maintenance mode while functionality is being consolidated from there and some other places into the new OAuth2 part of Spring Security 5.

See [this post from the Spring team](https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/30/next-generation-oauth-2-0-support-with-spring-security) for detailed information!

Comment: Thanks for the direction! For those who interested, a feature matrix can be found here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that spring can handle the old protocol OAuth (V1), too. So you have to be shure which version you are using, both are not compatible to each other.

For securing your application, refer to this guide: https://ordina-jworks.github.io/microservices/2017/09/26/Secure-your-architecture-part1.html
It provides information for many spring components and their interaction. Here, of course, OAuth2 is used.